# inconsistency in MySql table_schema data?

Tags: mysql, database

I have tables `A` and `A_backup` which are `identical`.
After summing table `A` metrics by its keys (in order to compress it),
table `A` has ~1 million less records, but is larger in volume than table `A_backup` by 100 MB -  according to `table_schema`.
the query I used:

```
SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name),       
   table_rows rows,
   data_length DATA,
   index_length idx,
   data_length + index_length  total_size,
   index_length / data_length  idxfrac
FROM   information_schema.TABLES a
where table_schema = 'my_schema'
ORDER  BY data_length + index_length DESC;
```

Does that make sense for some reason I don't see?